# Retrieving all user accounts on an accessible external Active Directory server over LDAPS

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I need to connect to an external LDAP server that is accessible to me but only over LDAPS.

The information I have available is username, server, password. I need to query and retrieve a list of all users. The format I have the details in are

- Username: domain\username
- Password: {password}
- Domain: remote.{domain}.net.au

The following code I wrote will authenticate my user account successfully, but I now need to enumerate all users which is where I'm having issues. Ideally this would be ALL users in the directory, not from within a specific OU. Again, I don't have the fully qualified paths to any OUs for this server. The server has a self signed certificate which is why in my example I am specifically telling it to accept the certificate.

```
        int port = secured ? 636 : 389;

        LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer, port, false, false));

        if (secured)
        {
            connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
            connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        }


        connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += (conn, cert) => { return true; };
        connection.Bind();

        return connection;
```

Comment: I discribe [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457140/608772) three ways to access to Active-Directory using C#. Do you really need to use System.DirectoryServices.Protocols ?

Comment: @JPBlanc I don't care how I do it just so long as it works. Using the LdapConnection is the only way I've been able to get LDAPS working thus far with this server which I believe is due to it's certificate errors. If it was standard LDAP it would be no problem as I have plenty of working code talking straight to my AD server. This one, however, is another organisations and we can only talk to it over LDAPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is in [Performing a Simple Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx#sdspintro_topic5_simplesearch) sample of Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P) with :

```
// create a search filter to find all objects
string ldapSearchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
```