# LDAP to a mainframe environment

Tags: c#, vbscript, ldap, linq-to-ldap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying an LDAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452531/querying-an-ldap-in-c-sharp)

I'm currently transposing some old ASP code from VBScript to C# and have gotten stuck on a piece that uses LDAP to connect to our IBM Top Secret environment. Any one know of some documentation / resources regarding the process or that could translate the relevant code to C# / .NET?

```
Set oLdap = CreateObject("LDAPClient")
oLdap.Connect "MY SERVER NAME",1389,"cn=" & <MF Account>, <MF Password>
oLdap.Search "host=ldap,o=COMP, c=us","tssacid=<Target UserID>"
```

*edit* I believe i'm getting closer with this:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://SERVERADDR/tssacid=acidval,tssadmingrp=acids,host=ldap,o=comp,c=us");
```

Solved my issue using this resource:

ftp://ftp.ca.com/pub/ldap/docs/ldapv3/eTrust_LDAP_Server_Administrator_Guide_30.pdf

I'll duplicate the resource in the "exact duplicate" thread

Comment: This question is not related to mainframe, right? If so, please remove the mainframe tag.

Comment: This does relate to mainframe, does it not? I'm looking to enumerate profile information from the TopSecret/Mainframe environment, not the AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the existing SO thread, there's also a [LINQ to LDAP](http://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/) provider on CodePlex. You could use that as an alternative to the existing Directory Services API in .NET (it's built on top of it, actually).