# Different approaches for finding users within Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I'm a newbie to AD programming, but after a couple of weeks of research have found the following three ways to search for users in Active Directory using the account name as the search parameter:

**Option 1 - FindByIdentity**

```
Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.MachineName)
Dim u As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "MYDOMAIN\Administrator")
If u Is Nothing Then
    Trace.Warn("No user found.")
Else
    Trace.Warn("Name=" & u.Name)
    Trace.Warn("DisplayName=" & u.DisplayName)
    Trace.Warn("DistinguishedName=" & u.DistinguishedName)
    Trace.Warn("EmployeeId=" & u.EmployeeId)
    Trace.Warn("EmailAddress=" & u.EmailAddress)
End If
```

**Option 2 - DirectorySearcher**

```
Dim connPath As String = "LDAP://" & Environment.MachineName
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry(connPath)
Dim ds As New DirectorySearcher(de)
ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(anr={0}))", Split(User.Identity.Name, "\")(1))
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeId")
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
Dim src As SearchResult = ds.FindOne()
If src Is Nothing Then
    Trace.Warn("No user found.")
Else
    For Each propertyKey As String In src.Properties.PropertyNames
        Dim valueCollection As ResultPropertyValueCollection = src.Properties(propertyKey)
        For Each propertyValue As Object In valueCollection
            Trace.Warn(propertyKey & "=" & propertyValue.ToString)
        Next
    Next
End If
```

**Option 3 - PrincipalSearcher**

```
Dim ctx2 As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.MachineName)
Dim sp As New UserPrincipal(ctx2)
sp.SamAccountName = "MYDOMAIN\Administrator"
Dim s As New PrincipalSearcher
s.QueryFilter = sp
Dim p2 As UserPrincipal = s.FindOne()
If p2 Is Nothing Then
    Trace.Warn("No user found.")
Else
    Trace.Warn(p2.Name)
    Trace.Warn(p2.DisplayName)
    Trace.Warn(p2.DistinguishedName)
    Trace.Warn(p2.EmployeeId)
    Trace.Warn(p2.EmailAddress)
End If
```

All three of these methods return the same results, but I was wondering if any particular method is better or worse than the others?

Option 1 or 3 seem to be the best as they provide strongly-typed property names, but I might be wrong?  My overall objective is to find a single user within AD based on the user principal value passed via the web browser when using Windows Authentication on a site (e.g. "MYDOMAIN\MyUserAccountName")

Comment: Options 1 and 3 would be *better" for me since they return nice `UserPrincipal` objects with many values as nice, discoverable properties (`User.DisplayName`, `User.Email` and so on) on that object - while #2 is a bit of a guessing game - there's everything inside the `DirectoryEntry.Properties` but you cannot really discover it easily....

Comment: Yes that's what I was eluding to - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me 1 and 3 are quite the same. In [Querying an LDAP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6457140/608772) answer, I introduce a third way using managed code which is low level (native LDAP) protocol with [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx).

I don't know if your purpose is just to authenticate a user or authenticate a user and retrieve some datas (profile) from Active-Directory, but keep in mind that a LDAP query is first a query, and the old fashion (your solution 2) let's you specify the properties you retrieve. Before choosing, make some test on a performance point of view.

If you just want to authenticate you can compare [native LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033489/608772) and [user Principal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499716/608772) responses from another article

Comment: Just going back to your point on performance.  When using UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity, the query takes 4.5 seconds to complete.  When using PrincipalSearcher, it takes only 15ms.  Have you any pointers why there is such a massive difference please?

Comment: First do you make multiple tests ? not on the same user. Perhaps FindByIdentity is more generic, where PrincipalSearcher just map a LDAP search.

Comment: Yes good point, you got me there.  To be honest looking at the structure of PrincipalSearcher it is the best option anyway as it allows a detailed search query to be constructed using strongly-typed values.  FindByIdentity is a bit simplistic in comparison.