# How to get and filter AD first & last name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I am trying to search by AD username and display the First and Last Name to a table.

This is what I have so far:

```
DirectoryEntry myLDAPConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://company.com");
DirectorySearcher dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(myLDAPConnection);
```

I understand I need to do something with my `dSearch` object to filter what is returned, but I have no clue what to do beyond this.

Comment: We used ldap to query against active directory this question has some good resources it looks like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452531/querying-an-ldap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }

    // find the group in question
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

    // if found....
    if (group != null)
    {
       // iterate over members
       foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
           // do whatever you need to do to those members
       }
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!